# Android- im trying to reset my timer every time a button is clicked, and when not clicked for 5 secs ,need it to go back to original page(activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, onclick, reset

I'm trying to reset my timer every time a button is clicked, and if not clicked within 5 seconds, it should go back to the original page (activity).

Code so far:

```java
clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(seconds==5000){timer.cancel();} //It crashed when I added this line

        counter++;

        seconds = 5000;
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Intent x =  new Intent(startClickActivity.this, ClickCountActivity.class);
                startActivity(x);
            }
        }, seconds);
    }
});
```

I don't know what kind of timer to use or if I should be using threads.

Comment: i put this before counter

if (seconds==5000)
        {timer.cancel();}

it crashed....

Answer (score 9):

This should be inside your class.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
   public void run()
   {
      Intent x =  new Intent(startClickActivity.this, ClickCountActivity.class);
      startActivity(x);
   }
}
```

And this in old place.

```
// ...
// Your code
MyTimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
final long seconds = 5;
timer.schedule(task,seconds*1000L);
clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {                                                                   
      counter++;
      task.cancel();
      task = new MyTimerTask();
      timer.schedule(task,seconds*1000L);
   }
});
```

I think it should work well :)

By the way, your code:

```
if(seconds==5000)
   timer.cancel();
```

Will always cancel/terminate your timer, because `seconds` variable is set by you and always is 5000.

Comment: omg thank you bro works good the only thing is i dont want the timer to start unless the button is clicked first

Comment: Is there not a way to reset it? Rather than delete it and recreate it.